# Use exisiting URL as login

Tags: django, templates, url, redirect

I am a Django newbie and need some help with the following. Every time someone needs to login to my app, I want them to be directed to an existing authentication URL: https://example.com

I have set up the following urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="login.html"), name="login"),
              ]
```

I have a login.html template"

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<body>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

 <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper"> 
            <a>Quality Dashboard IDM</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
           
            </ul>
            </div>
        </nav> 

<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of using this template I want to do something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', url=https://example.com),
              ]
```

How do I basically paste that URL into my app, so every time I type in the IP-address, it takes me to https://example.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is what you want, you can directly redirect the URL to some other URl from the urls.py itself.

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('some_existing_url/', RedirectView.as_view(url='http://www.google.com')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```